# Specify link to PDF with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

I have the following html code for displaying a PDF file in my AngularJS application:

```
<div id="pdf">
  <object width="100%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" data="./test.pdf?#zoom=45&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">                
  </object>
</div>
```

How can I specify some link that might change dynamically and get it from a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the link to the scope in the controller like this?

```
$scope: {
        pdflink: 'https://link/to/pdf/',
    },
```

Then add the pdflink like bellow:

```
<div id="pdf">
  <object width="100%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" data="{{data.pdflink}}" id="pdf_content">  
  </object>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thanx, i thought i have to use angular-specific syntax for the value of "data". It works!

Answer (score 1):

Without your controller code or any context it's hard to provide a detailed answer but assuming that your pdf file name is in a controller property something like:

```
<div id="pdf" ng-controller="pdfController as pdf">
  <object width="100%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" data="{{pdf.fileName}}?#zoom=45&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">                
  </object>
</div>
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you probably *should* use [Angular specific syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) for this, because otherwise you might get some annoying error messages in the console if the file changes dynamically.

```
<object ng-attr-data="{{controller.pdf}}"></object>
```